# State store partitioned iterator?

Tags: apache-kafka-streams

I have a Kafka-streams transformer which functions like a windower: it accumulates state into a state store in `transform()` and then forwards it in an output topic during `punctuate()`, with the state store topic partition key the same as the input topic.
During `punctuate()`, I would like each StreamThread to only iterate its own partition of the state store to minimize the amount of data to be read from the backing kafka topic. But the only iterator I can get is through

```
org.apache.kafka.streams.state.ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<K,V>.all()
```

which iterates through the whole state store.

Is there any way to "assign partitions" of a state store and make `punctuate()` iterate only on the assigned partitions?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I guess, `ReadOnlyKeyValueStore<K,V>.all()` does what you want. Note, that the overall state is sharded into multiple stores with one shard/store per partitions. `all()` does not iterate through "other shards". "all" means "everything local", ie, everything from the shard of a single partition.

Comment: That's what I thought at first, but I was getting logs suggesting otherwise: different threads are processing  the exact same amount of lines at the same time, and since my data is almost randomly partitioned, it would seem unlikely unless they were all processing all shards. I'll chalk it up to coincidence then. Thanks.

Comment: @Vincent if different threads are processing the same amount that might indicate that the messages are spread to partitions in equal amounts.